# Phusion Passenger Web application could not be started / picks wrong ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, passenger

My RoR app fails to start, with error:

> It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install
>   all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please
>   run:
>
> bundle install
>
> If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your
>   application being run under a different environment than it's supposed
>   to. Please check the following:
>
> ```
> Is this app supposed to be run as the railsapp user?
> Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
> ```

and

```
Ruby interpreter command

    /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

The file config/environment.rb is owned by the railsapp user. 
I use rbenv, and installed ruby version 2.1.1 as the global version. 
I use bundler to install the gem dependencies. which is all OK.

So it seems, phusion passenger picks the wrong ruby version (At least not the one I installed as global with rbenv).

### How do I make Phusion passenger compile mod_rails with the ruby version installed with rbenv?

when I ran: passenger-install-apache2-module, I noticed it picked up the system installed ruby version from ubuntu as:

```
* Checking for Ruby development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux/ruby.h
```

but 'which ruby' as railsapp user gives this:

```
/home/railsapp/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

My gem environment is like this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/railsapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/railsapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/railsapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/railsapp/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/railsapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /home/railsapp/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/railsapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin
     - /etc/rbenv/libexec
     - /home/railsapp/.rbenv/shims
     - /etc/rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use the PassengerRuby configuration option. See the official documentation.

Comment: and how and where needs the OP to do that? It might answer the question but doesn't it need a little bit more context?

Comment: Thanks Hongli, read the manual he? BTW in the docs you mention the 'global server configuration' , so what do you mean by this?

Comment: @rene The official Phusion Passenger website, under "Documentation", of course. Isn't that the obvious first place to look for documentation?

Comment: @user2736833 The web server config file consists of contexts. There is a global context, per-virtual host context, per-location context, etc.  For Apache, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context. Nginx doesn't have equivalent documentation but the concept is the same.

Comment: @Hongli I'm not saying that it is not obvious to look there but I hoped you could summarize here what is found in that documentation...but maybe that is just me...

Answer (score 2):

For apache/nginx you can do the following:

```
which passenger-config

rvm use 2.2.1 # Use the version you want

opt/passenger/bin/passenger-config --ruby-command # Use the path that was returned by the firth command.
```

Source: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#setting_correct_passenger_ruby_value

Comment: Let me add to the correct answer next step: then open sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site.conf and change old version ruby to new

Answer (score 0):

**Apache/Passenger specific**

I've done this, and the answer to this lies in the `httpd.conf` (usually located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) Apache `LoadModule` gets all out of whack when you update Ruby or passenger versions.

Near the bottom of a correctly configured file, you'll see a section which might say something like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-  4.0.48/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.48
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
```

Change the `LoadModule` making sure to update `ruby-2.X.X` and `passenger-X.X.X`. You'll have to update Passenger's dependencies as well, [which are best done through a reinstall (so you generate the correct symlinks).](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6)